# Custom List Definition using Document LIbrary

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a Custom List definition based on the Document Library list. My List definition appears under the Custom Lists group in "Create Page" but when I try to instantiate a new List based on the custom definition  by entering the Name and the definition and clicking Create-

It displays the Error Page with error message ***"File Not Found."***

Any ideas on what that file may be that the runtime is looking for.

Comment: Check the 12/logs for more info on what is missing and post that here as an update.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the log entries I find two that I think may be related -

1. Failed to find the XML file at location '12\Template\Features\\feature.xml'
2. and a repeating set of four entries like the one below-

Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID 'e2205d5b-5eda-40f8-b5e4-3f97d2375059'.  Skipping this feature for element querying consideration.
Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID '53b158d4-921d-4d17-99a7-6d3727611198'.  Skipping this feature for element querying consideration.
Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID '08d4396c-80a1-427d-9b6f-da64ba153f43'.  Skipping this feature for element querying consideration.
Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID '72a1f18e-c4d4-4e3c-b531-e1ccf702489e. ' Skipping this feature for element querying consideration.

-Dont know why it is trying to find the XML file in point 1. (that folder was deleted sometime ago)
-I think these entries are for the ***features for which I deleted the Folders without first Unistalling and Deactivating the Features***.

Comment: No 2: Check this out iand see if it can help you: http://www.moss2007.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2008/04/28/stsadm-o-export-fatalerror-failed-to-compare-two-elements-in-the-array.aspx